# Limit bandwidth of Apache (XAMPP)

Tags: bandwidth, xampp

I want to limit the bandwidth available to my XAMPP Apache on Windows 7, so I found something about the module 'mod_bw'. I copied the file ("mod_bw.dll") in the modules directory and added the following lines to my httpd.conf.

```
LoadModule bw_module modules/mod_bw.dll
BandWidthModule On
ForceBandWidthModule On
BandWidth all 65536
```

But with this in the configuration my apache won't even start. I noticed all the other modules have the file extension '.so' while I've got mod_bw.dll. Is this making a difference?

This is the guide I was following: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/BandwidthLimiting

Comment: It doesn't matter it's backwards compatible. The .so is preferred, but the .dll will work just fine. What does your apache error log say? What version of apache are you using? As I think mod_bw has issues with 2.4 or 2.+ in general. Try mod_ratelimit if you're just trying to slow users down, it won't limit (i don't think) overall bandwidth usage but will limit how much bandwidth each user can take.

Comment: Great. I've posted it as an answer then if it's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter, it's backwards compatible.

The .so is preferred, but the .dll will work just fine.

What does your apache error log say?
What version of apache are you using?

As I think mod_bw has issues with 2.4 or 2.+ in general.

Try mod_ratelimit if you're just trying to slow users down, it won't limit (i don't think) overall bandwidth usage but will limit how much bandwidth each user can take.